# Storing values in database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to be able to store the data added from the user input in the multiple textboxes.  That way when the program is closed the data entered is not lost.

This is currently how I get input displayed into the DataGridView

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Try
        InfoTableAdapter.Insert(CInt(txtRound.Text), CInt(txtScore.Text), CDec(txtSlope.Text), CDec(txtCourse.Text), CDate(txtDate.Text))
        Me.InfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.RoundDataSet.Info)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error with database")
    End Try
End Sub
```

If someone could point me into the right direction it would be much appreciated YouTube and Google have failed me.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: ... and you have to improve your searching skills.

Comment: `site:stackoverflow.com tableadapter update database` == 6900 hits; almost half in VB.NET